# Using pow() to power tow variables

Tags: c

I have 2 variables and after i gave those number to computer it power them 
like:

And I want to do this: `a^b`. Then print it:

```
int a ; 
int b ; 
scanf ("%d" , &a);
scanf ("%d" , &b);
```

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: Please explain your question in further details

Comment: `printf("%g\n", pow(a, b));`

Answer (score 1):

`man pow` says:

> double
>   pow(double x, double y);
>
> ...
>   The pow() functions compute x raised to the power y.

You need to include math.h. 
In code it would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int a, b;

    if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong input for a");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(scanf("%d", &b) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong input for b");
        exit(1);
    }
    double result = pow(a, b);
    printf("result of %d^%d=%g\n", a, b, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that `scanf` returns the number of input items assigned. So it makes sense to check for invalid input there.